# Browser FireFox is hidden when selenium webdriver tests run

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, teamcity

I use TeamCity as Continuous Integration and Selenium Webdriver tests written in Java code.
When I launch my tests, they all seem to run (becaue in TC it shows the final passed/failed number of tests), but I don't see any FireFox browser on the TeamCity Agent machine, where they run.

I check the processes tab in task manager and can see the firefox.exe -foreground process started, but don't see any browser in UI

How can I enable browser to display when I log in with my_admin_user?

NOTE: the TC agent service is started with "Log on as: my_admin_user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If TeamCity Agent run as service on machine it uses 'background' desktop to run FF (as I understood all services do the same). You need to start agent manually from cmd.

I have an simmilar issue, my tests fail on TC agent - they can't open url in chrome, but when I'm running them on local machine they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable and start interctive service.
2. Open Teamcity agent services and services Go to Properties-> Logon tab and select checkbox "Allow service to intect with Desktop"...

You will get a interctive seiver popup nexttime asking to allow to run on desktop.